# NumPy : array methods and functions not working

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I have a problem regarding NumPy arrays.

I cannot get array methods like .T or functions like numpy.concatenate to work with arrays I create:

```
>>> a=np.array([1,2,3])
>>> a
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> a.T
array([1, 2, 3])
>>> np.concatenate((a,a),axis=0)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
>>> np.concatenate((a,a),axis=1)
array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3])
>>>
```

However when I create an array using bult-in functions like rand everything is fine

```
>>> a=np.random.rand(1,4)
>>> a.T
array([[ 0.75973189],
       [ 0.23873578],
       [ 0.6422108 ],
       [ 0.47079987]])
>>> np.concatenate((a,a),axis=0)
array([[ 0.92191111,  0.50662157,  0.75663621,  0.65802565],
       [ 0.92191111,  0.50662157,  0.75663621,  0.65802565]])
```

Do you think it has to do with element types (int32 vs float64) ?

I anm running python 2.7 on windows 7

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
a = np.random.rand(4)
```

and then I think you'll find it works the same.

In general with numpy you really need to pay attention to the shape and axes of your arrays.  The shapes `(4,)`, `(4,1)`, and `(1,4)` are all differently and will behave different in most situations.

For example:

```
a = np.random.rand(4)
print a.shape, a.T.shape  # (4,) (4,)

b = np.random.rand(1,4)
print b.shape, b.T.shape  # (1,4) (4,1)
```

Comment: I see... But how am I supposed to create a 1x4 array with the values I want so that I will be able to use methods and functions ?

Comment: Ok I found it... I have to use ndmin=2 parameter

Comment: If you want to use `ndmin` you can, but it seems like a better idea to me to explicitly state the dimension of the arrays, but just realize that a 1D array is different than a 2D array, even with a single row or column.